# REST API design: how to handle resources that can also be sub-resources

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I have to put a (read-only) REST service atop of an existing product database. The easy part is having a top level product resource, like:

```
/api/products/
```

Now, actually callers of this service will rather need to get their relevant products based on the ID of a store and of a specific process (like "retail"). Behind the scenes, the combination of those two values results in a configured subset of products. This must be transparent for the caller, it should not need to know about these "product portfolios".

So I thought about designing the URI like this, where 1234 is the StoreID and retail is the process:

```
/api/stores/1234/retail/products
```

The first question that comes up here is if I should return full products here or URIs to their individual resources on /api/products/ ... the pro would be clearly that the caller does not need to retrieve each individual product from /api/products, the con would be that this would cause a caching headache on the /api/stores/1234/retail/products URI.

To complicate things, those products of course also have prices. Also here, a product does not have one price, but multiple ones that is also dependent of the StoreID and the Process, besides other factors. In reality, prices are direct children of products, so:

```
/api/products/ABCD/prices
```

would be the obvious choice, but again, as StoreID and Process are relevant to pre-filter the prices, an URI like:

```
/api/stores/1234/retail/products/ABCD/prices
```

would be more appropriate.

At the same time, there are other subresources of products that will not make sense to have under this URI, like product details. Those would clearly only make sense directly under /api/products/ABCD/details as they are not dependant on the store or process.

But this looks somehow messy to me. But at the same time, solving this by only having queryparam filters to solve it directly on the product resource, is not much nicer and does not enforce the caller to provide both, StoreId and process:

```
/api/products?store=1234&process=retail
/api/products/ABCD/prices?store=1234&process=retail
```

Even more, process or storeid does not have anything to do with the product, so querying for it directly on product seems odd. For prices, it would make sense, though.

So my question is: is there a good way to solve this that i don't see? And: would you recommend returning full products when they are a subresource - and what do you think about handling (HTTP) caching when doing that?

Comment: Just from a first quick look: If `store` and `process` are parameters of the `products` resource, I guess it's cleaner to keep them there even if you retrieve sub-resources. Matrix-parameters for the rescue - `/api/products;store=1234;process=retail/ABCD/prices`. Generally speaking, a good URI design does not make a service more RESTful then one with a more complicated URI as the client will learn everything it needs from server responses anyway - in a true RESTful environment though! Most REST services should not call themselfs RESTful but rather `API service on top of HTTP or ASOTOH`

Comment: Makes absolutely sense, but the one problem with exposing this directly over the /api/products URI is that the combination of store and process actually has special meaning and reduces the set of data I'm selecting from. For example, passing only the store ID would still select from ALL products, whereas passing both of them selects only from a configured subset. That's why I thought that having a special URI when querying for that special scenario would make more sense, even more because store and process are not directly associated with a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first question that comes up here is if I should return full
>   products here or URIs to their individual resources on /api/products/
>   [...] the con would be that this
>   would cause a caching headache on the /api/stores/1234/retail/products
>   URI.

I would definitely return the full products - imagine the amount the client would have to do if it would simply want to display a list of product names. Ideally this endpoint would be paginated (query string can include something like `&pageSize=10&pageNumber=2`, for example).

Also there are various caching solutions around this - for example you can cache all the products in a data structure service like Redis.

> To complicate things, those products of course also have prices [...]
>   and details subresource.

Looking at the [Richardson Maturity Model level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), this would be where links come into play, and you could have something like this under a product resource:

```
<link rel = "/linkrels/products/ABCD/prices" 
      uri = "/products/ABCD/prices?store=1234&process=retail"/>
```

and another similar link for the product details resource.

@Roman is right, REST is meant to be discoverable, clients should simply follow links (that can have long/ugly uris), instead of having to memorize them (like in SOAP, for example).

Comment: Thanks Alexandru. Thinking about prices, it would definitely make sense to not have them under the /stores/... URI as, in comparison to products, they are not part of this required Store/Process combination. They can be queried by that too, but that does not reduce their subset of prices to select from whereas this is the case for products when this combination is given. This is why I think it makes sense to have a special URI when the configured subset of products for a store/process combination should be taken into account, whereas on /api/products I always select from the full set of data.

Comment: As for links, yes, that's how I plan to do it, providing links to sub- or related resources in my responses. But I don't plan to implement HATEOAS, that's why I didn't mention RESTful anywhere :)

Comment: @CodingByLuck then update your post please and remove the `REST` keyword from the title and tag as this indicates that you want to have a RESTful solution, which also includes HATEOAS as this is [one of the few architectural constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) REST has!

Comment: @RomanVottner No offense, I know the theory, but the reality is simply different. I won't tag my post as "API service on top of HTTP" because it will not really help to get my question discovered as the whole world names such a service REST service, wrong name or not. That's the wrong place for a HATEOAS flamewar, so I leave it to that.

Comment: @CodingByLuck No offense here either, but just as the whole world jumps down a bridge, is it safe to assume it to be the right thing? Name things as they are, otherwise you have to expect critics pointing out the little differences ...