# Terminology question: API somewhere between SOAP and REST - what is the name for them?

Tags: rest, api, soap, terminology, api-design

#### My understanding of SOAP vs REST:

- REST = JSON, simple consistent interface, gives you CRUD access to 'entities' (Abstractions of things which are not necessarily single DB rows), simpler protocol, no formally enforced 'contract' (e.g. the values an endpoint returns could change, though it shouldn't)
- SOAP = XML, more complex interface, gives you access to 'services' (specific operations you can apply to entities, rather than allowing you to CRUD entities directly), formally enforced, pre-stated 'contract' (like a WSDL, where e.g. the return types are predefined and formalized)

Is that a broadly correct assessment?

#### What about a mixture?

If so, what do I call an API that is a mixture?

For example, If we have what at surface level *looks* like a REST API (returns JSON, no WSDL or formalized contract defined - but instead of giving you access to the 'entities' that the system manages (User, product, comment, etc) it instead gives you specific access to services and complex operations (/sendUserAnUpdate/1111, /makeCommentTextPurple/3333, /getAllCommentsByUserThisYear/2222) without having full coverage?

The 'services' already exist internally, and the team simply publishes access to them on a request by request basis, through what would otherwise look like a REST API.

#### Question:

What is the 'mixture' typically referred to as (besides, maybe, a bad API). Is there a word for it? or a concept I can refer to that'll make most developers understand what I'm referring to, without having to say the entire paragraph I did above?

Is it just "JSON SOAP API?", "A Service-based REST API?" - what would you call it?

Thanks!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at all those so-called REST-APIs your observation might seem true, though REST actually is something completely different. It describes an [architecture or a philosophy whose intent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s) it is to decouple clients from servers, allowing the latter one to evolve in future without breaking clients. It is quite similar to the typical Web page interaction in that a server will teach a client on what it needs and only reacts on client-triggered requests. One has to be pretty careful and pendant when designing REST services as it is too easy to include a coupling that may affect clients when a change is introduced, especially with all the pragmatism around in (commercial) software engineering. Stefan Tilkov gave a great talk on REST back in [2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) that, alongside with [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc) or [Asbjørn Ulsberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY), can be used as introduction lectures to what REST is at its core.

The general premise in REST should always be that a server teaches clients what they need and what a server expects and offers choices to the client via links. If the server expects to receive data from the client it will send a form-esque representation to inform the client about the respective fields it supports and based on the [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) of the respective elements contained in the form a client knows whether to select one or multiple options, enter some free text or enter a date value and such. Unfortunately, most of the media-type formats that attempt to mimic HTML's forms are still in draft versions.

If you take a look at [HTML forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) in particular you might sense what I'm refering to. Each of the elements that may occur inside a form are well defined to avoid abmiguity and improve interoperability. This is defacto the ultimate goal in REST, having one client that is able to interact with a sheer amount of other services without having to be adapted to each single API explicitely.

The beauty of REST is, it isn't limited to a single representation form, i.e. JSON, in fact there is almost an infinite number of possible representation formats that could be exchanged in a REST environment. Plain `application/json` is a terrible media-type for REST applications IMO as it doesn't include any defintions in regards to links and forms and doesn't describe the semantics of certain fields that may be shipped in requests and responses. The lack of semantical description usually leads to [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) where a recipient expects that receiving data from i.e. `/api/users` returns some specific user data, that may differ from host to host. If you skim through [IANA's media type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) you will find a couple of media-type formats you could have used to transfer user-related data and any client supporting these representation formats whold be able to interact with this enpoint without any issues. Fielding himself claimed that

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types). ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

Through content-type negotiation client and server will negotiate about a representation format both support and understand. The question therefore shouldn't be which one to support but how many you want to support. The more media-type your API or client is able to exchange payloads for, the more likely it will be to interact with other participants.

Most of those so-called REST APIs are in reality just RPC services exposed via HTTP that may or may not respect and support certain HTTP operations. HTTP thereby is just a transport layer [whose domain is the transfer of files or data over the Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s). Plenty of people still believe that [you shouldn't put verbs in URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694967/1377895) when in reality a script or process usually doesn't (and shouldn't) care whether a URI contains a verb or not. The URI itself is just a pointer a client will follow and invoke when it is interested in receiving the payload. We humans are also not that much interested in the URI itself in regards to the content it may return after invoking that URI. The same holds true for arbitrary clients. It is more important what you ship along with that URI. On the Web a link can be annotated with certain text and/or link relation names that set the links content in relation to the current page. It may hint a client that certain content may be invoked before the whole response was parsed as it is quite likely that the client will also want to know about that. [`preload`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) i.e. is such a link-relation name that hints the client about that. If certain domain-specific terms exist one might use an extension scheme as defined by [Web linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2) or reuse [common knowlege](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/) or [special microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values).

The whole interaction in a REST environment is similar to [playing a text-based computer game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=7m01s) or following a certain process flow (i.e. ordering and paying produts) defined by an application domain protocol, that can be designed as a state machine. The client is therefore guided through the whole process. It basically just follows the orders the server gave it, with some choices to break out of the process (i.e. cancel the order before paying).

SOAP on the otherhand is, as you've stated, an XML-based RPC protocol reusing a subset of HTTP to exchange requests and responses. The likelihood that when you change something within your WSDL plenty of clients have to be adapted and recompiled are quite high. SOAP even defines its own security mechanism instead of reusing TLS, which requires explicit support by the clients therefore. As you have a one-to-one communication model due to the state that may be kept in process, scaling SOAP services isn't that easy. In a REST environment this is just a matter of adding a load-balancer before the server and then mirroring the server n-times. The load-balancer can send the request to any of the servers due to the [stateless constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)

> What is the 'mixture' typically referred to as (besides, maybe, a bad API). Is there a word for it? or a concept I can refer to that'll make most developers understand what I'm referring to, without having to say the entire paragraph I did above?
>
> Is it just "JSON SOAP API?", "A Service-based REST API?" - what would you call it?

The general term for an API that communicates on top of HTTP would be `Web API` or `HTTP API` IMO. [This article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/09/understanding-rest-and-rpc-for-http-apis/) also uses this term. It also lists `XML-RPC` and `JSON-RPC` besides SOAP. I do agree with Voice though that you'll receive 5 answers on asking 4 people about the right term to use. While it would be convenient to have a respective term available everyone would agree upon, the reality shows that people are not that interested in a clear separation. Just look here at SO on the questions taged with [rest](/questions/tagged/rest). There is nothing wrong with not being "RESTful", though one should avoid the term `REST` for truly RPC services. Though I think we are already in a situation where the term `REST` can't be rescued from misusage and [marketing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001799/rest-api-design-how-to-handle-resources-that-can-also-be-sub-resources/39012401?noredirect=1#comment65389191_39012401).

For something that requires external documentation to use and that ships with its own custom, non-standardized representation format or that just exposes CRUD for domain objects I'd add `-RPC` to it, as this is more or less what it is at its heart. So if the API sends JSON and the representation to expect is documented via Swagger or some other external documentation`JSON-RPC` would probably the most fitting name IMO.

To sum up this post, I hope I could shed some light on what REST truly is and how your observation is flawed by all those pragmatic attempts that unfortunately are RPC through and through. If you change something within their implementation, how many clients will break? In addition to that you can't reuse the client that you've implemented for API A to interact with API B (of a different company or vendor) out of the box and therefore have to either adapt your client or create a new one solely for that API. This is true RPC and therfore should be reflected in the name somehow to hint developers about future expectations. Unfortunately, the process of naming things propperly, especially in regards to `REST`, seems already lost. There is a fine but tiny group who attempt to spread the true meaning, like Voice, Cassio and some others, though it is like fighting windmills. The best advice here would be to first discuss the naming conventions and what each participant understand on which term and then agree on a naming scheme everyone agrees on to avoid future confusion.

Comment: Fascinating read. Thanks for taking the time. Really broadened my understanding of these concepts and how they fit together. Especially with respect to 'REST' and what it's actually supposed to mean, v.s. the "So Called REST" APIs I hear it used to refer to all the time.

Answer (score -1):

> My understanding of SOAP vs REST
>
> ...
>
> Is that a broadly correct assessment?

No.

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is an "architectural style", which is to say a coordinated collection of architectural constraints.  The World Wide Web is an example of an application built using the REST architectural style.

[SOAP](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/) is a transport agnostic message protocol specification, based on [XML Information Set](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/)

> If so, what do I call an API that is a mixture?

I don't think you are going to find an authoritative terminology here.  Colloquially, you are likely to hear the broad umbrella term "web api" to describe an HTTP API that isn't "RESTful".

The whole space is rather polluted by [semantic diffusion](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiffusion.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your answer - which part of my understanding is not correct? I understand that REST is not just an API protocol - but in terms of an API endpoint you're looking at, is this typically what a developer would expect from SOAP vs REST - or just me?